How to run Outlook macro at a scheduled time?
I configured an Outlook macro as a button under a certain tab. I want to run that macro at a scheduled time.
Can a vbscript invoke a click action on that button? If not, can I run the vbscript outside of Outlook to invoke the macro execution?
The macro in ThisOutlookSession works when run manually.
Sub DownloadIPOInstruments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strDate As String
Dim strNewFileName As String
Dim strFilePath As String

' Specify the folder path where you want to save the attachment
strFolderpath = 
"C:\Users\hengj\Desktop\IPO_Instrument_Report_Daily\"

' Specify the date format in the subject
strDate = Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") ' Change the date format as per 
your subject, report is T-1 date.

Set objOL = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Loop through each email in the Inbox folder with the specified 
subject
For Each objMail In objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'IPO 
Instrument Report_" & strDate & "'")
Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments
' Loop through each attachment and save it to the specified 
folder
For Each objAttachment In objAttachments
' Specify the new file name for the attachment
strNewFileName = "IPOInstrumentReport.xls"
' Build the full file path
strFilePath = strFolderpath & strNewFileName
' Check if the file already exists
If Dir(strFilePath) <> "" Then
' Delete the existing file
Kill strFilePath
End If
' Save the attachment to the specified folder path
objAttachment.SaveAsFile strFilePath
' Rename the file to the new file name
Name strFilePath As strFolderpath & strNewFileName
Next objAttachment
Next objMail

Set objAttachment = Nothing
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub

I want to automate the macro by scheduling it to run at a certain time by using the below code.
Private Sub Application_Startup()
' Adjust the time to match your desired schedule (8:15 am)
Dim scheduledTime As Date
scheduledTime = TimeSerial(8, 15, 0)

' Calculate the time until the next scheduled run
Dim timeUntilScheduled As Date
timeUntilScheduled = Date + scheduledTime - Now

' Schedule the macro to run at the specified time
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + timeUntilScheduled, 
Procedure:="DownloadIPOInstruments"
End Sub

It is throwing

run time 438 error,  Object doesn't support this property or method


Use calendar appointment in outlook to trigger VBA macro or Run a code every half an hour

I have the below code that is functioning well when i run it manually as a macro button in outlook.

Application object (Outlook) does not support Application.OnTime method (Excel).

The code is set up to run outside of Outlook, Excel for instance.

This question is similar to: Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
